# WCF service with webHttpBinding not working when configurations are added in web.config

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, webhttpbinding

I have a very basic WCF service that I want to run on IIS as a RESTful service. Here is the service contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IRestCameraWs
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/cameras/{username}",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
   CameraInfo[] GetUserCameras(string username);

   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/liveimage/{cameraId}",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
   byte[] GetLiveImage(int cameraId);

   //void GetLatestImage(int cameraId, out DateTime timestamp, out byte[] image);

   [OperationContract]
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/latestimage/{cameraId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
   string GetLatestImageUrl(int cameraId);
}
```

There is a class which implements this contract called `StopMotion.Business.WCFService.RestCameraWs`. Then I added an `.svc` file in my web project with following markup.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="StopMotion.Business.WCFService.RestCameraWsBase"%>
```

When I navigate to this service url, it shows me service home page and a link to wsdl definition. But when I add configuration in my `web.config` file to configure this service on `webHttpBinding` I get following error page from IIS express.

[image]

First I thought I am doing something wrong with configuration. Later I deleted the configuration and just changed the factory in svc file like

```
<%@ ServiceHost Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" Service="StopMotion.Business.WCFService.RestCameraWsBase"%>
```

`WebServiceHostFactory` is said to use `webHttpBinding` by default and we don't need to add this in configuration unless we need something more out of it. But changing factory also resulted in the same error page on IIS Express.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Looking in my configs, I remember that I had to declare the end point in the web.config and enableWebScript in the behavior. Part of the result looks somewhat like :

```
    <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="svcservice.svc.IAuthsvc" bindingConfiguration="bc.svcservice.svc.AuthsvcJSON" behaviorConfiguration="epb.svcservice.svc.AuthsvcJSON"/>      
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <behavior name="epb.svcservice.svc.AuthsvcJSON">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
```

Hope this can be helpful

Comment: thanks jbl. I haven't yet reached that far. But sooner or later i got to be needing this one. +1 and many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my method signatures. we can only have parameters of type `string` which are included in `UriTemplate` whereas some of methods were accepting parameters of type `int` like following.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/latestimage/{cameraId}",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string GetLatestImageUrl(int cameraId);
```

When i debugged it on vs dev server, it laid the error on line for me but it seems that observing the error is more difficult in IIS Express even in the dev environment.